# can someone explain how this python code doesn't give an error

Tags: python, indentation, if-statement

So I have inherited a rather crappy piece of code. Indentation is as I found it. Why does the else not throw an error? The code will never reach it as far as I understand.

```
    for l in range(1,9):
        indexes = pickle.load(open('%s_%d.pkl'%(fc,l)))

        clusters_sum = sum([indexes[i]['count'] for i in indexes])
        print >> out, 'Lane %d: %d clusters PF.\n%8s  %9s  %5s' % (l,clusters_sum,'Index','Count','%')
        for i in sorted(indexes, key=lambda x: indexes[x]['name']):
            pct = indexes[i]['count'] and indexes[i]['count']/clusters_sum*100 or 0
            if pct < 0.06: continue
            print >> out, '%8s  %9d  %5.1f' % (indexes[i]['name'], indexes[i]['count'], pct)
        else: print >> out
```

Comment: Do you think else should fail because it is used on a `for` block, or because the `print >> out` line is not on a new line with an extra indent?

Comment: I think you have it backwards in that it will always reach it ...

Comment: Does this follow a style guide? I would love to see the rest of the guide :)

Comment: No I had assumed the else was on the if statement. I wasn't aware that  you can have an "else" on for loops in Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the documentation on [`else` clauses on loops](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops), this is valid syntax and the code within the `else` block is executed as long as there was no `break`, `return`, or uncaught exception within the loop.

In this particular case the `else` clause will always be executed since none of the above conditions (other than an exception) can happen, so it is equivalent to the following:

```
    for l in range(1,9):
        indexes = pickle.load(open('%s_%d.pkl'%(fc,l)))

        clusters_sum = sum([indexes[i]['count'] for i in indexes])
        print >> out, 'Lane %d: %d clusters PF.\n%8s  %9s  %5s' % (l,clusters_sum,'Index','Count','%')
        for i in sorted(indexes, key=lambda x: indexes[x]['name']):
            pct = indexes[i]['count'] and indexes[i]['count']/clusters_sum*100 or 0
            if pct < 0.06: continue
            print >> out, '%8s  %9d  %5.1f' % (indexes[i]['name'], indexes[i]['count'], pct)
        
        print >> out
```

Comment: Of course, in this case, it will be executed unconditionally since there is no chance to `break` from that loop ...

Comment: OK, I hadn't seen that before. Is there any advantage to this over the way you have written it, (which is the way I would have expected).

Comment: There isn't any advantage in this case.  It is useful in cases where you want to know that there was no `break` in the loop, for example say you are looping over a list trying to find a particular element, and there is a `break` statement when the element is found.  Inside of the `else` clause you would handle the case where the element does not exist in the list.

Answer (score 2):

`for` loops can have an `else` clause.

From http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops:

> Loop statements may have an else clause; it is executed when the loop terminates through exhaustion of the list (with for) or when the condition becomes false (with while), but not when the loop is terminated by a break statement.

Since the loop doesn't contain a `break` statement, the `else` clause will *always* be executed.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you're not understanding the indentation (or lack thereof) on the else statement, or the fact that there is an "else" on the for loop. If the former case...

The formatting is valid because `print >> out` is a "simple statement".

Here is the grammar for a [for statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement):

```
for_stmt ::=  "for" target_list "in" expression_list ":" suite
              ["else" ":" suite]
```

Notice that after the colon in the optional "else" block, it wants a "[suite](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#grammar-token-suite)", the grammar of which is...

```
suite         ::=  stmt_list NEWLINE | NEWLINE INDENT statement+ DEDENT
statement     ::=  stmt_list NEWLINE | compound_stmt
stmt_list     ::=  simple_stmt (";" simple_stmt)* [";"]
```

So, it's possible in python to create a list of simple statements as an alternative to a block of statements. This is also valid...

```
for i in sorted(indexes, key=lambda x: indexes[x]['name']):
    pct = indexes[i]['count'] and indexes[i]['count']/clusters_sum*100 or 0
    if pct < 0.06: continue
    print >> out, '%8s  %9d  %5.1f' % (indexes[i]['name'], indexes[i]['count'], pct)
else: print >> out; print >> out; print >> out
```

and would be equivalent to...

```
for i in sorted(indexes, key=lambda x: indexes[x]['name']):
    pct = indexes[i]['count'] and indexes[i]['count']/clusters_sum*100 or 0
    if pct < 0.06: continue
    print >> out, '%8s  %9d  %5.1f' % (indexes[i]['name'], indexes[i]['count'], pct)
else:
    print >> out
    print >> out
    print >> out
```

However, I think most people would prefer seeing the second syntax.

Comment: I had assumed the else was on the if, not the for loop.